# Getting rid of outlines in HTML form elements that browsers display?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webforms

Is there a way to do this? It differs from browser to browser what outline is displayed and such (Safari and its blue glow, Firefox and its dotted outline when clicking a submit button...)

CSS is preferable, but JS is fine too.

Comment: You mean when the element has the focus? You should mention that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The outline can be removed by resetting the `outline` property:

```
input:focus, button:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: #efefef;
}
```

However, you should include another visual indicator, as I have done here, to indicate that the element is focused, for accessibility reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're talking about the outline property. To remove outlines you can do this;

```
element { outline:none; }
```

Although I don't recommend it for usability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the default properties of the items in CSS, such as `border`, `background` and the like, the default appearance of those elements will no longer prevail.

You can set borders of widths, colors and styles as you like for buttons, inputs and fieldsets, for example. Also, the background (colors and/or images) will alter those default appearances.

Answer (score 0):

```
selector{
outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si Yi Jiang's answer for a code-level solution. There's also a [good article](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2010/04/13/towards-a-cooler-focus-caret/) on Sitepoint.

The blue glow (focus ring) in Safari is a Mac OS X user preference. The user can adjust how/when that appears.

- in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Full Keyboard Access, check "Text boxes and lists only"
- in Safari > Preferences > Advanced > Universal Access, uncheck "Press Tab to highlight each item on a web page"